# Trying to add selected image views by(OnItemClickListener), between fragments, on the second ImageView the app crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to add and show a multiple image views existing in a fragment to another in the same activity by OnItemClickListener on GridView.

I was able to add the first image view but when I add the second one the app crashes.
By the way, I'm adding the image views to a linear layout inside Horizontal Scroll View.

Here is the layout of the first fragment:

```html
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_fragment_id"
    >
    
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/items_id_gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10.0dip"
            android:verticalSpacing="10.0dip"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The layout of the second fragment:

```html
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/play_36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/play_button" />


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sentenceBarScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/play_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play_button"
        android:padding="1dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sentence_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

        </LinearLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout of the main activity:

```html
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home"

    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/sentence_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/sentenceBarFragment"
                android:name="ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.SentenceBarFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sentence_layout"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
    <!-- put contents fragments here :) -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the class of the first fragment.

```
sendItemToSentenceBar connector;

//for retrieving the values of the image stored in database 
private Item item;

static  ArrayList<Integer> back;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

back=new ArrayList<>();
    DBConnection dbConnection= new DBConnection(getActivity());
    GridView gridView=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.items_id_gridView);

    final ArrayList<Item> items2=new ArrayList<>(dbConnection.getAll(Cat_id));

    ContentAdapter dataAdapter=new ContentAdapter(getActivity(),items2);
    gridView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            item=items2.get(position);
            if(item.getType().equals("Category"))
            {
                back.add(Cat_id);
                changeFragment(item.getID());
                AddNewDialogFragment.Cat_id=item.getID();

            }else {
                speak(item.getName());
                connector.sendData(item);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and I'm using an interface to pass the data from OnItemClickListener to the other fragment by "connector.sendData(item);"

Here is the interface:

```
public interface sendItemToSentenceBar {
// send item to the sentence bar fragment :)
void sendData(Item item);
}
```

Then in the class of the other fragment
There is the method AddItem(Item item) that should add the image view to the second fragment, the first image view can be added be on the second one the app just crashes :

```
private ArrayList<Item>  items;

private LinearLayout sentenceLayout;
private View itemView;

private ArrayList<View> itemsViews;
View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View sentenceBarFragment=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sentence_bar_fragment,container,false);
    sentenceLayout  =   sentenceBarFragment.findViewById(R.id.sentence_bar);
    itemView        =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item,sentenceLayout,false);


return  sentenceBarFragment;
}

public void AddItem(Item item){

        TextView name_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
        name_id.setText(item.getName());

        ImageView image_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        image_id.setImageBitmap(convertByteToBitmap(item.getImage()));
        itemsViews.add(itemView);
        sentenceLayout.addView(itemsViews.get(0));

items.add(item);
    }
```

Finally the method AddItem(Item item) is used in the class of the main activity that contain both of the fragments:

```
@Override
public void sendData(Item item) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    SentenceBarFragment s= (SentenceBarFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.sentenceBarFragment);
    s.AddItem(item);
}
```

Here the Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
    at ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.SentenceBarFragment.AddItem(SentenceBarFragment.java:95)
    at ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.Home.sendData(Home.java:129)
    at ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.ContentFragment$2.onItemClick(ContentFragment.java:83)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

of the Logcat, I could identify those errors:

```
at ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.SentenceBarFragment.AddItem(SentenceBarFragment.java:95)
```

which is at the class of the second fragment, in the method AddItem(Item item)

```
sentenceLayout.addView(itemsViews.get(0));
```

.

```
at ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.Home.sendData(Home.java:129)
```

which is at the class of the main activity, in the used method 
sendData(Item item)

```
s.AddItem(item);
```

.

```
at ye.com.ebra.contentfragments.ContentFragment$2.onItemClick(ContentFragment.java:83)
```

which is in the class of the first fragment, in OnItemClickListener:
    connector.sendData(item);

Sorry for the long post, but I'm really stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be repeatedly modifying and adding the same `item_view` object inflated in `onCreateView(...)` method.  It strikes me that you need to inflate a new object each time you call "AddItem".

There is also a possible issue with appending views to the `itemViews` list but repeatedly adding the first view in the list (ie. not the one you just added) .

So `SentenceBarFragment` might look instead like this:

```
private ArrayList<Item>  items;

private LinearLayout sentenceLayout;

private ArrayList<View> itemsViews;

@Nullable
@Override    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View sentenceBarFragment=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sentence_bar_fragment,container,false);
    sentenceLayout  =   sentenceBarFragment.findViewById(R.id.sentence_bar);
    return  sentenceBarFragment;
}

public void AddItem(Item item){

    // inflate a new view to be added
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_item,sentenceLayout,false);

    TextView name_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
    name_id.setText(item.getName());

    ImageView image_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
    image_id.setImageBitmap(convertByteToBitmap(item.getImage()));

    // add the view you just inflated
    itemsViews.add(itemView);
    sentenceLayout.addView(itemView);  // or addView(itemViews.get(itemViews.size()-1))
    items.add(item);
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked really well, the image does show in the second fragment and its text does get read by text to speech engine. It's just the text doesn't show and I have searched a lot about it, but nothing works. I'm using the same method that you corrected for me(addItem) to set the text for the image's TextView. Hope you could help me with this.

Comment: On further consideration, my suggestion would be to change your `sentenceBar` `LinearLayout`  and its enclosing `HorizontalScrollView` with a horizontal `RecyclerView` and populate it using an adapter based on your `items` list.  This a more standard approach than dynamically adding child views to XML-defined layouts.